# Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0

Tags: swift, swift4

I use framework (no Carthage, no Pods) with the only way to copy it to the project. After compiling I get the error:

```
Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0:
/Path/To/Framework/Module/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

Cleaning and building project again didn't work. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Comment: From the Xcode 9 GM release notes: *"Neither Swift 3.2 nor Swift 4.0 support linking with targets compiled with any earlier versions of Swift, including Swift 3.1"*

Answer (score 5):

No, you need to compile all your Swift binaries with the same Swift version. ABI stability (which is the cause of your problem here) is deferred to the next Swift version (although it was originally planned for Swift 3 if I recall correctly). You can keep track of this feature [here](https://swift.org/abi-stability)

Until Swift has ABI stability, you will need to recompile your source code with every Swift release.

**EDIT:** As Shai Mishali pointed out, unfortunately ***ABI stability*** won't be enough without ***Module format stability***

Comment: It's important to note the has nothing to do with ABI stability specifically - Shipping ABI stability won't resolve binary swift frameworks.

Comment: can you explain further more? i'll be happy to correct my answer if needed. ABI stability will let us use binaries from different Swift version together, what's incorrect here?

Comment: "ABI stability is necessary, though not sufficient, for binary frameworks. Module format stability is also required and is beyond the scope of this document." : https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/ABIStabilityManifesto.md#what-does-abi-stability-enable

Comment: well, looks like ABI stability has something to do with this issue anyway :)